# Applying multiple CSS classes to same text in TinyMCE

Tags: cakephp, tinymce

I am having some issues getting TinyMCE to be as flexible as I need it to be.  In my editor (used in a cakePHP-based app) I am not allowing users to edit the html, so we are relying entirely on the WYSIWYG.  Unfortunately, TinyMCE is currently not allowing users to apply two CSS classes to the same text.  Whichever style is applied last wipes out the original.

**To give an example:**  If a user wants to designate a line of text to be both 'huge' and 'highlighted' (both CSS classes), they would highlight the text and choose 'huge' from the CSS style dropdown, then highlight the same text again and choose 'highlighted'.  What results is text that *only* has the 'highlighted' class applied to it.

I can work around this problem currently by just adding an extra character to the text I am trying to style, apply the 'huge' class to that, apply the 'highlighted' class to the original text, and then delete the extra character.  But, this really is far from an ideal solution.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write your own plugin looking similar to the style plugin.
When the user selects a class from the dropdown you just add it to the selected text instead of replacing it.